# How to undefine "multiple" environment variables in makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I have several shell environment variables that I would like to undefine in make environment.

I know that I can undefine ASHELLENV, but I am trying to use wildcards to pattern match environment variables, then for each on undefine, but not having any luck.

I thought something like this would work, but shell env still remains.

```
$(foreach v, SOMEENVS_% SOMEOTHERENVS, $eval(undefine $$(v))
```

Comment: I thought something like this would work, but shell env still remains ==>

Comment: I thought something like this would work, but shell env still remains in make environment

Comment: You are trying to do two tricky things: constructing a lit of variables according to some pattern, and undefining all of the variables in a list. Can you do either of these by itself?

Answer (score 0):

I mean, your syntax is not right (for example eval is a makefile function, you have to write it as `$(eval ...)`).

You can do what you want like this (look up the various functions etc. in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)):

```
$(foreach v,$(filter SOMEENV_%,$(.VARIABLES)) SOMEOTHERENV,$(eval undefine $$v))
```

Comment: Yup, syntax was wrong, and the solution works, and I was missing the filtering on .VARIABLES. Thanks!